# vmstat -m / slabtop number of objects and memory leak

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

Suppose I have some Linux kernel module (driver), which has its own slab, which is allocated e.g. something like this (from within kernel through the kernel patch, not in driver):

```
kmem_cache_create("some_drv_obj_cache", sizeof(struct some_drv_obj), 0,
                  SLAB_HWCACHE_ALIGN | SLAB_PANIC, NULL);
```

Being used in the driver this slab is reflected in the output of the commands `vmstat -m` and `slabtop`.
Suppose I do `rmmod some_drv` and still see some objects in cache (`vmstat -m`) like this:

```
Cache                       Num  Total   Size  Pages
some_drv_obj_cache           36     36    320     12
```

Does it guarantees that there is some memory leak in driver? I.e. the `Num` value must be zero after unloading?
The second question is that when I generate some events, which guaranteed to add new objects to slab cache, does this `Num` (number of slab objects) necessarily updated in real-time one by one (i.e. one object created - Num incremented by one)? Or this value can be updated by chunks?

Comment: "Suppose I do `rmmod some_drv` and still see some objects in cache..." - The merely existence of `some_drv_obj_cache` means a leak: the driver forgot to delete the cache upon exiting. As for actualization, `vmstat -m` just periodically reads information from procfs. Every read returns actual information. But between reads the information is staled.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry for misinformation. The cache itself is created from within kernel (through kernel patch). So this is not memory leak. But the `Num` is still unclear.

Comment: @Tsyvarev *`vmstat -m` just periodically reads information from procfs* - what do you mean by periodically? I invoke `vmstat -m` periodically by hand or with `watch -d -n1` and `Num` == 36 for a long time and doesn't decrease. Please explain what you mean

Comment: So nothing is calling `kmem_cache_shrink` or `kmem_cache_destroy`?

Comment: @IanAbbott Nope. It's just like xfrm does with [`xfrm_dst_cache`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.262/source/net/xfrm/xfrm_policy.c#L2939). The mentioned driver is a some kind of equivalent.

Comment: If your driver is the only one using the cache, you could try shrinking it with `kmem_cache_shrink` during module exit and check if there are any slabs remaining in the cache. The return value is 0 if all slabs were released, or non-zero if slabs remain in the cache (but the return value is not the actual number of slabs).

Comment: @IanAbbott What do you mean by *"slabs were released"*? These slab-objects have `genid` based on which they can be migrated from cache to gc (garbadge collector) list. They also can be reference counted (e.g. `dst_entry`). So seems that there could be a case when driver is already unloaded but object is still in gc list with non-zero reference count.

Comment: @budoattack I must admit I do not know the innards of the mm code all that well, but it would be nice to see what effect calling `kmem_cache_shrink` (at module exit time) has on your `vmstat -m` output (if you think it's worth it).

Comment: @IanAbbott This driver does `flow_cache_flush()`. Does it significant?

Comment: @budoattack I hadn't heard of `flow_cache_flush()` before you mentioned it. (I haven't done anything with network drivers.) Well, the flow cache was removed in kernel 4.14, so hopefully I'll never need to know much about it. :-)